# Can I split marshallering phase to generate DOM Tree

Tags: xml, dom, marshalling

I have to generate a file Xml using Dom.

When invoke (using 4gb) method Marshaller.marshal(Object obj, Node dom) I get error about out of memory.

If I try to generate DOM tree with 8gb it works.

Do you know if exists a way to split the execution of marshaller and then merge it?

I can't use Stax or Sax.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do it will be to break up your object tree. Marshal those partial sections separately and then merge the generated strings. You could even do some of the outer levels of the XML file by hand and write out the generated sections to the file as they are generated rather than keeping them in memory.

Fundamentally if you are running out of memory then you are better off using SAX rather than DOM though. One of the main advantages of SAX is exactly this, the reduced memory footprint.